# linux "enable -n xxx" command works in terminal but not when put into a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I've found a very strange issue, when in linux terminal I type "enable -n trap", it would disable the trap linux builtin command. But if I put it into a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
enable -n trap
```

and then run the script, there's no error but the command is also not disabled. Really appreciate if someone could share what is happening and how to run it in some file instead of directly in the terminal. Thank you!

Comment: Place "enable -n trap" on  a different line from  "#! /bin/bash".
The enable / enable -n is only valid inside the script; but you can source the script or put the command in your $HOME/.bashrc to affect you interactive shell.

Comment: Could you give an example of your script? Note: `enable` works only inside that script.

Answer (score 2):

The `enable` command only affects *the current shell*. When you run a script, that script is executed in a new process, so:

1. A new shell starts
2. The `enable` command runs and disables the `trap` command in that shell
3. The shell exits

If you want to affect the *current* shell, your only option is to source the script using the `.` (or `source`) command. If the script is named `disable-trap.sh` and is in your `$PATH`, you can run:

```
. disable-trap.sh
```

You can also provide a full path to the script:

```
. /path/to/disable-trap.sh
```

Sourcing a script like this is largely equivalent to typing the same commands in at the command line: it executes the instructions in the script in the current shell, rather than spawning a new process.

Comment: Thank you! That really resolves my doubt. Another thing I'm wondering is that when I used "enable -n enable", and given that it seems there's no "disable" command on my machine, is there a way I could enable it again?

Comment: I guess just exit the shell and start a new one?

Comment: Thank you, yeah that's true. 
The background here is that I have a docker linux container, and the I want to capture the guest user's(who use kubectl exec into the container) input command and send it to container log, by adding a trap statement in /etc/bash.bashrc. Meanwhile I want to disable user's ability to override trap's behavior, so I come up with this idea.